# Golang uses JDBC or ODBC or what connection type

Tags: oracle, go, oracle-call-interface, oci8

go version go1.8.1 windows/amd64 and I am importing

```
"github.com/mattn/go-oci8" 
"database/sql"
```

For connecting to my oracle database. Here when I give db username, password, port and table name in connection string

```golang
func openAndConnectToDb(sbconfig ConnectorConfig) *sql.DB {
    logger := sbgoclient.Log
    logger.Println("Open the database")
    //  oraprop := LoadConfig("oraproperties.yml")
    fmt.Println("Load config complete")
    orrrr := sbconfig.DB_Username + "/" + sbconfig.DB_Password + "@" + "//" + sbconfig.DB_Ip + ":" + sbconfig.DB_Port + "/" + sbconfig.DB_Schema
    fmt.Println("orrr formed: ", orrrr)
    db, err := sql.Open(sbconfig.DbType, orrrr)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Println("database connection failed...")
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }

    //Use a backoff/retry strategy - we can start this client before
    //the database is started, and see it eventually connect and process
    //queries
    var dbError error
    maxAttempts := 20
    for attempts := 1; attempts <= maxAttempts; attempts++ {
        logger.Println("pinging database...")
        dbError = db.Ping()
        if dbError == nil {
            logger.Println("database ping successfull........")
            fmt.Println("database ping successfull........")
            break
        }
        logger.Println("Ping failed: ", dbError, "retry in ", attempts, " seconds.")
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(attempts) * time.Second)
    }
    if dbError != nil {
        logger.Fatal(dbError)
    }

    return db
}
```

It fails to connect, whereas in java if I specify username, password, port, servicename and tablename in JDBC connection string it connects successfully.

The output is

```
time="2017-10-10T13:43:02+05:30" level=info msg="Open the database" 
time="2017-10-10T13:43:02+05:30" level=info msg="pinging database..." 
time="2017-10-10T13:43:24+05:30" level=info msg="Ping failed:  ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
retry in  1  seconds." 
time="2017-10-10T13:43:25+05:30" level=info msg="pinging database..." 
time="2017-10-10T13:43:46+05:30" level=info msg="Ping failed:  ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred 
retry in  2  seconds."
```

Comment: `Here when i give db username...` where? Where is your code that fails and the error?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov i have updated my question with both code and output

Comment: Are you sure that connection string is correct? `user/pass@//127.0.0.1` seems odd to me.

Comment: @Peter yes user/pass@//127.0.01:1521/TEST_DATA it works for my local database...and when i try the same with remote database it fails and output i  have mentioned above

Comment: Then you won't find much help here, I'm afraid. Network timeouts can have many reasons, most of which don't have anything to do with your code. Start by verifying IP addresses and firewall configurations.

Comment: I'm agree with @Peter, according to [the doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/mattn/go-oci8#ParseDSN), the dsn should be in the form of `user:password@host:port/sid?param1=value1&param2=value2 `. Try this format.

Comment: JDBC is for Java (that's what the "J" stands for). Most Go DB drivers either directly implement database connectivity, or wrap a native DB driver library using cgo.

Comment: @Peter it works fine for sid like xe but if sid is xe.DATA then it fails to connect

Comment: @Adrian thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you exactly why your code ist not working, but I can provide you with some sample code I am involved in in an advisory capacity:

https://github.com/odbaeu/oracledb_metricbeat/blob/master/oracledb.go

Here the code fragment creating a new connection:

```
// NewDB returns a new oracle database handle. The dsn value (data source name)
// must be valid, otherwise an error will be returned.
//
//   DSN Format: username/password@host:port/service_name
func NewDB(ociURL string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    // NLS_LANG is set to American format. At least NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS has to be ".,".
    os.Setenv("NLS_LANG", "AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8")
    os.Setenv("NLS_DATE_FORMAT", "YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS")

    // Open DB connection
    oConn, err := sql.Open("oci8", ociURL)
    if err != nil {
        return oConn, errors.Wrap(err, "sql open failed")
    }

    return oConn, nil
}
```

Comment: do i need to set NLS_LANG is this compulsory

Comment: Best advice: first get it to work, then try without. My friend writing that package is an oracle specialist, I am more the go programmer. So I can not really answer that, sorry.

Comment: it works fine for sid like xe but if sid is xe.DATA then it fails to connect